# How to reduce vertical spacing of grid in Gantt chart?

Tags: gantt

need help to reduce the vertical spacing of the grid in a Gant chart. Tried several attempts with y grid and so on, but noting works. Hope someone can help!

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.1cm]  
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid,title height=.75, title top shift=0]{1}{25}
\ganttset{bar height=0.2}
\gantttitle{Week}{25} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,25}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{2}{4} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{5}{6} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{6} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{7}{11}
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a complete code that also has an appropriate preamble, i.e. starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. BTW, to mark code as such, put it in the cursor and press the `{}` button while editing. And as for your question: you probably need only to replace `[y=0.1cm]` by `[yscale=0.7,transform shape]` or another scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfgantt/y unit chart=0.7cm]  
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid,title height=.75, title top shift=0]{1}{25}
\ganttset{bar height=0.2}
\gantttitle{Week}{25} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,25}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{2}{4} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{5}{6} \\
\ganttmilestone{M 1}{6} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{7}{11}
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a so-called minimal working example (MWE), which can just be copied and compiled to make life easier for everyone.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you mayb have a fix for the suppressed text on the side? Because I want to go very low in scale :) @marmot

Comment: @user174212 What precisely do you mean by "suppressed text on the side"? (As far as I can see the text is still there, or am I missing something?)

Comment: ohh, sorry for my bad formulation.. I mean that the text gets pressed together in the vertical direction, and do you maybe have a fix to limit that.  Trying to save space since i have 46 tasks going in. @marmot

Comment: @user174212 Yes, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you so much for taking you time! @marmot